# Why the below program aborts when a std::vector<std::future<T>> is used.?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdvector, std-future

I wanted to perform hashing of a stream of input messages in multithreading, so was trying to implement

```
std::vector<std::future<HashData>> futures;
```

but the program aborts from abort.h when debugging in Visual Studio 2019.

Code Snippet:

```
std::vector<std::future<HashData>> futures;
std::vector<std::string> messages;

for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++)
{
  std::promise<HashData> promiseHashData;
  std::future<HashData> futureHashData = promiseHashData.get_future();
  futures.emplace_back(std::move(futureHashData));
  std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {PerformHash(std::move(promiseHashData), messages[i]);});
}

std::vector<HashData> vectorOfHashData;
// wait for  all async tasks to complete
for (auto& futureObj : futures)
{
  vectorOfHashData.push_back(futureObj.get());
}
```

```
void PerformHash(std::promise<HashData>&& promObject, std::string& message)
{
    ComputeHashUsingSHA256(message);
        HashData data;

    // set data for HashData object
    data.i = i;
    data.blocks = blocks;
    data.blocksize = blocksize;
    data.blockbufs = blockbufs;
    data.secs = secs;
    memcpy(data.digest, digest, SHA256_DIGEST_SIZE);

    data.has_hashdata = has_hashdata;
    memcpy(data.hashdata_buf, hashdata_buf, c_hashsize);

    promObject.set_value(data);

}
```

while debugging the code, observed as only few threads were created using async and  post that, the program aborts from abort.h as shown in this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZgOC.png)

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Your lambda is storing a reference to the local variable `promiseHashData`, you need to move the promise into your lambda

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you capture `promiseHashData` by reference. At each loop iteration it gets invalidated while the async thread performs computation on it.

You need to capture the instance of the promise by moving it into the lambda, like:

```
   std::async(std::launch::async, [promiseHashData2=std::move(promiseHashData)] ()mutable{PerformHash(std::move(promiseHashData2), messages[i]);});
```

Or use `std::async`'s feature of returning `std::future` while changing `performHash` to return `hashData`. Using both `async` and `promise` is redundant.

Comment: Here, i wanted the data type of futures.get() to be HashData, but when i used the future object returned by async as futureObj.get(), it was giving compilation error:  error C2664: 'std::future<_Ty>::future(const std::future<_Ty> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::future<void>' to 'std::future<_Ty> &&'

Comment: `HashData PerformHash(std::promise<HashData>&& promObject, std::string& message)
{
    ComputeHashUsingSHA256(message);
        HashData data;

    // set data for HashData object
    data.i = i;
    data.blocks = blocks;
    data.blocksize = blocksize;
    data.blockbufs = blockbufs;
    data.secs = secs;
    memcpy(data.digest, digest, SHA256_DIGEST_SIZE);

    data.has_hashdata = has_hashdata;
    memcpy(data.hashdata_buf, hashdata_buf, c_hashsize);

    return data;

} `

Comment: @devilsEye you need the lambda to return `hashData` as well. Currently it just calls the function and returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the good answer from @ALX23z and answer your comments there:

The reason you get that error is that `PerformHash` (and your lambda) returns `void`. The return value from `std::async` is `std::future<X>`, where `X` is the return value of the function you give `std::async`. Here is a small toy example:

```
struct HashData {std::size_t h;};

HashData performHash(const std::string &msg) // <- returns HashData
{
    HashData hd = {msg.size()};
    return hd;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> messages = {"Bla", "klaf", "this is a message"};
    std::vector<std::future<HashData>> futures;

    for (const auto &msg : messages)
    {
        auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]()
                              { return performHash(msg); }); // <- also returns HashData
        futures.emplace_back(std::move(fut));
    }

    std::vector<HashData> results;
    for (auto &fut : futures)
        results.push_back(fut.get());

    for (const auto &hash : results)
        std::cout << hash.h << '\n';
}
```

Also note that you can skip the lambda, and call `std::async` like this:

```
auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, performHash, msg); // performHash is a free function

// If performHash is a method of class HashCalculator - included for completeness sake
HashCalculator calc;   // Need an instance somewhere  
auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, &HashCalculator::performHash, calc, msg);
```

Comment: tried this,  the program aborts from abort.h when debugging in Visual Studio 2019 again. it's not resolving abort issue.

Comment: That sounds odd. If you go back in the stack trace until you hit your code, which line do you find there?

Comment: when we are iterating over vector of future objects, issue is from fut.get(). The get() method on future object is the place from where the program tries to abort.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like the type of error you get when you try to call `get()` on a `std::future` twice. On the first call to `get()` the result is extracted from the shared state, and the shared state is released. This means that the future is no longer valid, and any subsequent calls to `get()` invokes Undefined Behavior.